# How can I install the ATI video card driver for Ubuntu 12.04? (ati radeon hd 3200)

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, video

I don't know if there really is an answer on this web site, I have searched a lot in all kinds of forums but I don't find the answer, I want to install my drivers the best way possible, but there is an error when I try to install the video drivers in the terminal. The error is: "Distro Version entered incorrectly or not supported, use --listpkg to identify valid distro versions". As I don't know what a distro version is I don't really understand this error, my ubuntu version is 32-bit, pleas help.

Comment: Possible duplicates:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/127690/12-04-boots-to-black-screen-ati-radeon-hd-3200   **and** http://askubuntu.com/questions/8875/how-can-i-solve-display-glitches-and-poor-performance-with-ati-fglrx-driver-on-m

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the best way for me to install drivers is by using the "Additional drivers" option first before trying the cli method.

In your dash type "Additional" and that should bring up the additional drivers app.
Let it scan your system and then it should give you the drivers to choose from.
Install the "current" driver and see if that solves it for you.

Comment: do you know if it gives you the best performance for the graphic card? cause i did that before, but if i activate the compiz config options, the pc becomes slow, i read in a forum that there are problems with the ati drivers and thats why the compizconfig doesn't run smoothly, but i want to be sure, in the page i found there they mentioned the propietary drivers, if there is something more for this i would like to know, and thanks by the way.

Comment: I don't have any performance issues on mine. But it isn't the same model though. Mine is the HD5750